# How to replace LDAP Authentication from Azure AD B2C?

Tags: spring-security, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, spring-ldap, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a requirement to replace the LDAP Authentication from a gateway microservice with Azure AD B2C, Is there any standard way or steps to replace that with newer authentication method or we need to completely do that from scratch to provide the implementation through Azure AD B2C.

Answer (score 0):

There's a write-up [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-migration) and some custom policy samples [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples#user-migration).

The main steps are:

- Migrate the users; either big bang or just in time. The main issue is that you need new passwords
- Replace the LDAP API that you use to authenticate with an appropriate B2C [code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/integrate-with-app-code-samples)
- Replace the LDAP user CRUD calls with the appropriate [Graph API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations)